# Android TextView: can I stop text that is partially displayed from appearing

Tags: android, user-interface, text, textview, xamarin.android

In my app I display several text views containing text of various length that is loaded in at run time. I do not know the dimensions of the text view or the length of the text until run time. Sometimes, when the text is long and the textview small some of the text is partially visible, for example:

[image]

I want to remove the partially visible text as it looks a bit naff, but I can't find a way to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: make your view scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

You can hard code the `TextView` height in a way that the second row of text will not be visible.

Or use:

```
android:maxLines , Makes the TextView be at most this many lines tall.
```

as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Put your textviews in a scrollview layout.And specify a specific width to your textview and make the height wrap content.So that your text doesn't get cut.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I can't change the width or height of the text view, they are part of a diary display and the height represents how long an event is. I was wondering if there was a way to remove any partially visible text given these constraints.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. I ran this code after the activity had loaded by posting the method CheckTextIsVisible to the parent relativelayout's handler queue, otherwise the height of the textviews will not be known:

```
m_eventsLayout.Post(new Action(CheckTextIsVisible));
```

Then the method CheckTextIsVisible finds each textview with text in it, calculates the height of the font, works out how many lines can fit in the textview, and sets the number of maximum lines accordingly:

```
    private void CheckTextIsVisible()
    {
        View view;
        TextView tView;
        Android.Text.TextPaint tPaint;
        float height;
        int heightOfTextView;
        int noLinesInTextView;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_eventsLayout.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            view = m_eventsLayout.GetChildAt(i);

            if (view is TextView)
            {
                tView = (TextView)view;
                if (tView.Text != "")
                {         
                    //calculate font height
                    tPaint = tView.Paint;
                    height = CalculateTextHeight(tPaint.GetFontMetrics());
                    //calculate the no of lines that will fit in the text box based on this height
                    heightOfTextView = tView.Height;
                    noLinesInTextView = (int)(heightOfTextView / height);
                    //set max lines to this
                    tView.SetMaxLines(noLinesInTextView);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private float CalculateTextHeight(Android.Graphics.Paint.FontMetrics fm)
    {
        return fm.Bottom - fm.Top;
    }
```

This results in no partially visible text!